# VSCode is just showing a blank screen when I open it in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS dual-boot

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here's a few details about the whole setup.

- I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS as a dual boot with Windows 11
- I installed VSCode using the instructions from the official Microsoft Website using the following commands:

  `sudo apt-get install wget gpg`

  `wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg`

  `sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg`

  `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'`

  `rm -f packages.microsoft.gpg`
- I had previously installed Visual Studio Code through Ubuntu Software and suddenly after the previous update I started facing blank screen issues when I open the VSCode. At the same time, if I launch the software using the option 'Launch using Dedicated Graphics Card' it works like a charm

I tried opening the software from terminal using the command `code --disable-gpu`. Although it works, I just want to get back to opening VSCode just with double-click.

Comment: [Reference link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) **Visual Studio Code on Linux**